# Paypal REST Api - AccessToken from a RefreshToken returns "Invalid_Request"

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

> Firstly, all keys are related to the SANDBOX environment

I've been fighting with PayPal REST API for the last couple of days, I'm trying to allow the users of my application to log in and allow me access to their accounts to perform services such as refunds, payment matching etc

So far i have a Winforms App with a browser inside, I redirect my user to:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize?client_id=AXg4eyTyKDAhYooB2rHgbt1FNHIr9Mh45EW0H1FPxnOKkt4j8MdyiTjJp1ELRhf15XC7hAe9QYrDG_Eq&response_type=code&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://XXX/Paypal/Confirm

They log in ... The inbedded browser scans the address and collects the returned 'code'. From here, i then POST to Paypal (/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice) with a grant_type of 'authorization_code' and collect the AccessToken and RefreshToken (Which i want to reuse).

This all works perfectly until i want to request another AccessToken using the earlier RefreshToken.

This is the returned JSON object:

```
{{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "28800",
  "refresh_token": "o_u5L17nQ4takc5ek_6QGMWl2lZA0jQThpMhURowJKNm6lBPFdkaLUzy0VFwXRg9xRA-ApjDkAIZm6hys_Yg1sLyjceaHIlGIKX_grDBeT5fOeEsPFKg6R9lHp8",
  "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJBWGc0ZXlUeUtEQWhZb29CMnJIZ2J0MUZOSElyOU1oNDVFVzBIMUZQeG5PS2t0NGo4TWR5aVRqSnAxRUxSaGYxNVhDN2hBZTlRWXJER19FcSIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTQ2NTgyOTc4MCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucGF5cGFsLmNvbSIsInNlc3Npb25JbmRleCI6IjIyYjJmNzRkMDA2YzExY2I4N2U3ZGZkY2Q3YjJjNWU0M2RhODljNDYiLCJpYXQiOjE0NjU4Mjk3ODUsImV4cCI6Mjg4MDAsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3dlYmFwcHMvYXV0aC9pZGVudGl0eS91c2VyL0F6V0VmSUtFdE1ldU1SN3laYS1LbkhOSTBPU2x1S2E1N1hVY082VE5sQ1EifQ==.q-JCp-d93CCaS0TgCdMqi9yVmHMzyAID7SbI7O81YwY",
  "access_token": "A015mqkkXEVVq0Va0BexS.hhQE0Dlzm36eKNS8-4CVLiIZs"
}}
    ChildrenTokens: Count = 5
    Count: 5
    First: {"token_type": "Bearer"}
    HasValues: True
    Last: {"access_token": "A015mqkkXEVVq0Va0BexS.hhQE0Dlzm36eKNS8-4CVLiIZs"}
    [Next]: Nothing
    Parent: Nothing
    Path: ""
    Previous: Nothing
    Root: {{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "28800",
  "refresh_token": "o_u5L17nQ4takc5ek_6QGMWl2lZA0jQThpMhURowJKNm6lBPFdkaLUzy0VFwXRg9xRA-ApjDkAIZm6hys_Yg1sLyjceaHIlGIKX_grDBeT5fOeEsPFKg6R9lHp8",
  "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJBWGc0ZXlUeUtEQWhZb29CMnJIZ2J0MUZOSElyOU1oNDVFVzBIMUZQeG5PS2t0NGo4TWR5aVRqSnAxRUxSaGYxNVhDN2hBZTlRWXJER19FcSIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTQ2NTgyOTc4MCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucGF5cGFsLmNvbSIsInNlc3Npb25JbmRleCI6IjIyYjJmNzRkMDA2YzExY2I4N2U3ZGZkY2Q3YjJjNWU0M2RhODljNDYiLCJpYXQiOjE0NjU4Mjk3ODUsImV4cCI6Mjg4MDAsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3dlYmFwcHMvYXV0aC9pZGVudGl0eS91c2VyL0F6V0VmSUtFdE1ldU1SN3laYS1LbkhOSTBPU2x1S2E1N1hVY082VE5sQ1EifQ==.q-JCp-d93CCaS0TgCdMqi9yVmHMzyAID7SbI7O81YwY",
  "access_token": "A015mqkkXEVVq0Va0BexS.hhQE0Dlzm36eKNS8-4CVLiIZs"
}}
    [Type]: Object {1}
    Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
    Dynamic View: Expanding the Dynamic View will get the dynamic members for the object
```

Just like the earlier request to '/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice' (That works!) i POST again to it, this time with grant_type of 'refresh_token'. This time the response is an exception:

```
"Unable to refresh access token - invalid_request - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#errors"}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233079
    HelpLink: Nothing
    InnerException: {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}
    Message: "Unable to refresh access token - invalid_request - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#errors"
    Response: Nothing
    Source: "PPTest_RESTSDK"
    StackTrace: "   at PPTest_RESTSDK.Wrapper.WebRequest.Post(Dictionary`2 Contents, String RelativeURL, String AccessToken) in C:\Development\DELME\_PPTest_RESTSDK\PPTest_RESTSDK\Wrapper.vb:line 432" & vbCrLf & "   at PPTest_RESTSDK.Wrapper.RegisterByRefreshToken() in C:\Development\DELME\_PPTest_RESTSDK\PPTest_RESTSDK\Wrapper.vb:line 294"
    Status: UnknownError {16}
    TargetSite: {System.String Post(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String], System.String, System.String)}
```

To remove the assumption that my code is at fault, i've recreated this using POSTMAN (Chrome Plugin). Running this will also recreate the exact same error that i'm seeing - See below.

The Authorization is a Base64 encoded version of my "client:secret" which equals:

Basic QVhnNGV5VHlLREFoWW9vQjJySGdidDFGTkhJcjlNaDQ1RVcwSDFGUHhuT0trdDRqOE1keWlUakpwMUVMUmhmMTVYQzdoQWU5UVlyREdfRXE6RUlYdklvQ3A1bVNRNDZ4RmhtS2VxbGR4anBzMGNIUkxBdTRFZnJnTXZBN3VRMXBaVFN0dWwyTlE1OVNIcjVydEYyeHZYVUNOOWxCT1FEd1g=

Client:
AXg4eyTyKDAhYooB2rHgbt1FNHIr9Mh45EW0H1FPxnOKkt4j8MdyiTjJp1ELRhf15XC7hAe9QYrDG_EqSecret: EIXvIoCp5mSQ46xFhmKeqldxjps0cHRLAu4EfrgMvA7uQ1pZTStul2NQ59SHr5rtF2xvXUCN9lBOQDwX

And this is the same result in POSTMAN:

[image]

Can someone tell me what on earth i'm doing wrong? I would very much appreciate it!!

Comment: your post looks fine but the refresh token in postman is different from the one in your first screenshot.

Comment: Yes you're quite correct - the error was in this post, but in code, i'm using the same refresh token. For the sake of clarity, i just re-registered a new auth code and generated a new refresh_token of (81hrG2lAY2916ocCs68kt8015dlWlEcKr2zjsGZC_V1zQ-s9POtYA4o4FSJVB3t35Euaxh9cnWVPm71TjYrUQhElJWopZSyAzgnpfrYMAD06hmDYcDAegk17a4k) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Update: Edited the post to reflect this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of fiddling i finally realised the problem.

By default, the application in Paypal Developer IS NOT given the rights to request Identity.

When setting up the App, you need to select and fully configure the information on the 'My Apps + Credentials' page. As soon as i did this, the refresh_token will now refresh.

I'm pretty annoyed with Paypal for allowing me to request an access_token and also for returning me such a pathetic and generic error though!!

Hope this revelation helps someone in the future!!

[image]